# Heroku app not launching : process exited with status 0

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I'm a beginner with discord bot on Python and I'd like to host one on Heroku's free tier. Just a simple one, so I can upgrade to something more complex afterwards.

So I upload [this](https://github.com/AlexandreBlanchon/Bots_for_discord) from Github and create the app (I don't use the discord_bot part at the moment). The build finishes without an error, but when I start the application it crashes and i get this log :

```
2018-09-22T21:37:30.267582+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `: python3 test_discord.py`
2018-09-22T21:37:31.001035+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-09-22T21:37:32.859278+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2018-09-22T21:37:32.877853+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

And... That's all. No error number, no detailed log, nothing i can look for in the heroku documentation.
The most intriguing part is the "status 0". Because from what I've learned looking on stack overflow, this means that everything is... fine !?

So I'm a little lost right here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of the log file looks suspicious

```
Starting process with command `: python3 test_discord.py`
                               ^^
```

The colon shouldn't be part of the command.

The reason for that colon is your [Procfile](https://github.com/AlexandreBlanchon/Bots_for_discord/blob/master/Procfile#L1), it has a surplus space:

```
worker : python3 testdiscord.py
      ^
```

It needs to be:

```
worker: python3 testdiscord.py
```

---

The exit code is 0 because a [colon in shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) does nothing and always returns with status 0.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry for bothering a whole community just for a surplus space...

Comment: No worries, that's quite a strange mistake. Maybe for future errors without output just put a print() somewhere in the file and you can immediately see whether that part of the script is executed at all.